# Questions about LocalScroll and ScrollTo (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scrollto

this problem might seem pretty trivial to some of you guys but i'm sorry i can't handle it.

Problem: I have one Div-Box called "DivBox" with the attribute `overflow:hidden;` and i want to display other information in it by scrolling to other divs inside of it.
Above I have links that refer to that other information.

```
<a href="#" id="LinkToInfo">Info</a>
<a href="#" id="LinkToInfo2">Info2</a>
<div id="DivBox">
  <div id="info1">Information</div>
  <div id="info2">other Information</div>
</div>
```

I also included jquery, ScrollTo, LocalScroll and Easing and wrote this code:

```
$('#LinkToInfo').click(function(){
  $('#DivBox').localScroll({
    target:'#info1'
  });
});
$('#LinkToInfo2').click(function(){
  alert("Debugging reasons");
  $('#DivBox').localScroll({
    target:'#info2'
  });
});
```

But it doesn't work. I tried debugging it but it did just not scroll. What am i doing wrong?

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: All you're trying to do is allow for scrolling within a pane by invoking a click and scrolling in that pane to the element?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/VTWxC/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but try removing the `href="#"` from the `<a>` tags.